# How can I share a link to site with Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to share an internet resource using my Google Drive to organize sharing. Is it possible to do so?

In the "Create" menu of Google Drive there are no such type, and I haven't managed to find anything in the list of additional apps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to do this without application. But google drive allows applications ;)

You need install this small plugin

[Google Chrome Web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/glinks/leanhbopikglhiejeckmchmobphcpphm/)

theirs site is here:

http://glinksapp.appspot.com/partials/support.html